# MeteorJS Get instance of a template

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteor-blaze

Is it a way to get an instance of a template from a call back function in Meteor to access data context and reactive var? Like use the id of the template to get it in another part of code.

Comment: To obtain an instance from a template goes like that: Template.instance().currentColor.get(); this means you've already attached the reactive 'currentColor' var to the template onCreate or onRendered. But what do you mean by callback function? Here is a link: https://dweldon.silvrback.com/template-instance

Comment: Hi thank for your reply, I mean to access to a template out side of  the template by exemple when you call a Meteor method and want access to the current template in the callback function of the meteor method.

Comment: You could preserve the instance and use it inside your callback event which would have to be located inside your current template event function. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Sorry I'm totally stupid, I have solved my problem, placing my React var at a global level. With this way I can go out of the template data context .Thank for you help.